# ionicframework: video src call is cancelled

Tags: angularjs, html5-video, ionic-framework

I have this code in my <ion-slide>

```
<ion-slide ng-repeat="item in lista track by item.nid">
    <div id="immaginiBox" >
        <div class="titolo">{{item.titolo}}</div>
        <blockquote class="desc" ng-show="item.desc != null"> 
            {{item.desc}}
        </blockquote>
        <img id="thumb_{{$index}}" ng-click="playVideo($index)" style="width:100%;" />
        <video style="display:none;" video-reset id="video_{{$index}}" controls="" width="100%" height="300px"></video>
    </div>
</ion-slide>
```

And this is my playVideo() function:

```
$scope.playVideo = function($index) {
    $ionicLoading.show(
        { 'template' : '<ion-spinner ng-hide="spinnerHide"></ion-spinner>'}
    );


    var video = document.getElementById('video_'+$index);
    video.src = $scope.lista[$index].videoT;
    $timeout(function() {video.play();});
}
```

Under IOS all works. Under Android (I have test only via emulator for the moment) video does not start because the call to video src is performed, but then immediately cancelled (I can see this in chrome developer tools).

Why this occurring?  Is there an alternative?

Comment: What happens if you use `ng-src` instead of `src`. Documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Comment: I need to set "video src" at run time. ng-src is useless in this situation.